# How to get windows explorer selection effect

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, effects

What I want is to get selection effect on windows explorer window 7 and 8.
I will use it on `TreeView`, do I have to use WPF?

The image below is a sample selection effect that I want, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Explorer Effect]

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeViewItem` class provides events like `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`, in which you can style the current item under the mouse cursor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem_events.aspx

The `TreeView` class also provides an event `SelectedItemChanged`, in which you can style the currently selected item in the tree view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.treeview_events.aspx

Comment: I am new in WPF, what style should I use

Comment: Border size, background colour, whatever you need to customize the tree view to be similar to your screenshot.

Comment: Are this class available in winform? I'd prefer winform if there